# Unable to view photos in img tag from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am able to upload the image to firebase storage and able to get the downloadable URL.

The problem is that if I copy that downloadable URL and paste it over to my . This is what i see below.
[image: preview]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Download link is not the same as resource link. To see image, your link should work like that: when you click it your image should show up in your browser directly. Only this `src` url would work.